# 2 Angular Services. Very similar code. Why do I get undefined for req.body in Express?

Tags: node.js, angular, express

I have two angular services that perform CRUD operations for different, but similar data objects. (Insider, outsider).

I'm trying to POST the data to the database with this code:

```
public postOutsider(out: Outsider){
    console.log(out);
    let fullUrl = `http://localhost:3002/api/outsiders`;
    let headers = new Headers({'Content-Type':'applicaion/json'});
    let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});
    return this.h.post(fullUrl,out, options)
                  .map(this.extractData)
                  .catch(this.handleError)
                  .subscribe(res => {
                    let not: Notification = new Notification();
                    //sends the update to the notification service...
                    not.message = 'Succussfully Saved Outsider';
                    not.timeStamp = new Date(Date.now());
                    not.response = res;
                    this.saveStatus.next(not);
                  });
  }
```

here is the backend code that processes the request:

```
create(req,res){
    log.info(req.body);
    return Outsider
      .create({
        firstName: req.body.firstName,
        preferredName: req.body.preferredName,
        middleName: req.body.middleName,
        lastName: req.body.lastName,
        address1: req.body.address1,
        address2: req.body.address2,
        city:req.body.city,
        state:req.body.state,
        zip:req.body.zip,
        country: req.body.country,
        currentContacts: req.body.currentContacts,
        maxContacts:req.body.maxContacts,
        expirationDate: req.body.expirationDate,
        areaCode: req.body.areaCode,
        language: req.body.language,
        emailAddress: req.body.emailAddress,
        gender: req.body.gender
      })
      .then(outsider => {
        log.info({createdOutsider: outsider});
        res.status(201).send(outsider);
      })
      .catch(err => res.status(400).send(err));
  }
```

The other object sends the data in the same manner. The back end code is operating in the same manner. The angular service is defined like this:

```
public postInsider(ins: Insider) {
    console.log(ins);
    let fullUrl = `http://localhost:3002/api/insiders`;
    let headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
    let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});
    return this.h.post(fullUrl, ins, options)
                  .map(this.extractData)
                  .catch(this.handleError)
                  .subscribe(res => {
                    let not: Notification = new Notification();
                    not.message = 'Successfully Saved Insider.';
                    not.timeStamp = new Date(Date.now());
                    not.response = res;
                    this.saveStatus.next(not);
                  });
  }
```

And the backend counterpart for that code.

```
  create(req, res) {
    console.dir(req.body);
    return Insider
      .create({
        firstName: req.body.firstName,
        preferredName: req.body.preferredName,
        middleName: req.body.middleName,
        lastName: req.body.lastName,
        address1: req.body.address1,
        address2: req.body.address2,
        city: req.body.city,
        state: req.body.state,
        zip: req.body.zip,
        maxContacts: req.body.maxContacts,
        currentContacts: req.body.currentContacts,
        releaseDate: req.body.releaseDate,
        gender: req.body.gender,
        areaCode: req.body.areaCode,
        language: req.body.language,
        institutionId: req.body.institutionId,
        country: req.body.country
      })
      .then(insider => {
        log.info({
          createdInsider: insider
        });
        res.status(201).send(insider);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        log.error({
          createInsiderError: err
        });
        res.status(400).send(err);
      });
  }
```

I do have a middleware in place that detects the body, and logs it out for troubleshooting, but it appears to be empty from the Outsider call.

The error I get back to the Angular app is as follows:

> errors : [{message: "Outsider.firstName cannot be null", type:
>   "notNull Violation", path: "firstName",…},…] 0 : {message:
>   "Outsider.firstName cannot be null", type: "notNull Violation", path:
>   "firstName",…} 1 : {message: "Outsider.lastName cannot be null", type:
>   "notNull Violation", path: "lastName", value: null,…} 2 : {message:
>   "Outsider.address1 cannot be null", type: "notNull Violation", path:
>   "address1", value: null,…} 3 : {message: "Outsider.city cannot be
>   null", type: "notNull Violation", path: "city", value: null,…} 4 :
>   {message: "Outsider.state cannot be null", type: "notNull Violation",
>   path: "state", value: null,…} 5 : {message: "Outsider.zip cannot be
>   null", type: "notNull Violation", path: "zip", value: null,…} 6 :
>   {message: "Outsider.country cannot be null", type: "notNull
>   Violation", path: "country", value: null,…} 7 : {message:
>   "Outsider.expirationDate cannot be null", type: "notNull Violation",
>   path: "expirationDate",…} 8 : {message: "Outsider.areaCode cannot be
>   null", type: "notNull Violation", path: "areaCode", value: null,…}

Why are these behaving differently?

Comment: whats the difference between log.info and console.dir ?

Comment: Log.info is handled by Bunyan and console.log is the standard one. Using standard for deeper debugging. Bunyan for dev and eventually production logging

Comment: im assuming you have verified that the front-end is added json to the body? you can check int he network tab of the browsers developer tools

Comment: Dir is to get the entire object...

Comment: Checking that, but it should be. It's essentially the same code for both

Comment: it looks like it is getting into the body

Comment: is the status code 200?

Comment: no. 400..... Adding the Error text to the question.

Comment: post the code surrounding the create? I don't see a problem with the posted code and maybe post the request made from the network tab to verify that post data is in the body

Comment: here's the gist of both the insider and outsider controllers in the Express app. 
https://gist.github.com/cjrutherford/8e0daba899d3bc98506d5dda4cd3e771